# A game has destroyed my colour settings permanently with no obvious cause, do I need to reinstall windows to rectify?

Tags: windows-10, gpu, colors, reinstall, nvidia

A game (Battlefield V) caused my colour scheme to appear washed out when active, but I once used sleep mode (Windows 10) with game running, and now it is permanently stuck like this regardless of whether the game is running or not. The only time it reverts to normal is when I start video captures with the native xbox capture thing, or when a video is full-screened such as youtube. There is no apparent change to the default settings in NVIDIA control panel, and I am scratching my head as to what has really happened. Should I just reinstall windows to rectify?

GPU is a NVIDIA 2070 super if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: Have you rebooted?

Comment: Have you tried to reboot your system

Comment: Does the nvidia control panel have a gamma adjustment?

Comment: Check it hasn’t just changed colour profile.

Comment: it definitely hasnt changed the colour profile, but since adjusting the gamma and a couple of the other sliders, it seems to work around the issue without addressing its cause. thankyou for your comments users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I just reinstall windows to rectify?

Possibly. After rebooting and you still have a problem:

**First - run DISM and SFC**

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth

SFC /SCANNOW

When done, restart, open Windows 10 settings, and go to System.  In the Search box (top left), enter Calibrate Display to get the Display Calibration screen. Follow that through to completion, restart and test.

If that fails, run a Windows 10 Repair Install

**Second - Windows 10 Repair Install**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Use the second link (Download).  Download the ISO file to a location, and from that location, run setup.exe

Follow along and select the option to Keep Everything.

Repair Install will also update most drivers during the repair.

Test after this is done.

**Third - Re-install Windows**

If none of the above work (Windows 10 normally works for me), only then, back up and re-install Windows. You can use Reset Windows in the Windows 10 Settings, Recovery section.

While I encourage you to back up, Windows Reset normally keeps your data.

Good luck

Comment: thanks, I've discovered playing with a few of the sliders in nvidia control panel seems to work around the problem without fixing it, but I'll try your suggestions if I have any more developments with the display. cheers for your help

Answer (score 0):

Before consider to reinstall Windows, I would recommend to download and install latest graphic driver from NVIDIA website for your model. Also we could upgrade system to latest Windows 10 20H2 with [ISO image](https://www.microsoft.com/zh-cn/software-download/windows10) to let it repair system issue during upgrade.

If all of them done but issue persists, we could try to clean installation to check.

Bests,